# Strange results in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qobject

I wrote a python class to do something:

- auto get the value from PyQt widgets into a dict,Save the dict data
  into file by pickle moudle
- auto set the widget's value base the dict    data read from file when
  the program start.

Now,the class work satisfactorily.

- main_pyfile:http://codepad.org/ewuQmiwa
- ui_pyfile:http:(delete)//codepad.org/Xw2xwTU3
- ui_uifile: http://sharesend.com/6tkj0vu3

I am trying to add a new feature about black list.
When line 37 in main_file is uncommented, the load_config functon doesn't work  properly.I don't know where the bug is on.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    #Created Time: 2015/8/25 17:46:50

    import os
    import sys
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
    import pickle
    import time
    import datetime

    class UiConfig(QtCore.QObject):

        def set_config(self, data):
            self.config_category = data.get('category', [])
            self.config_ignore = data.get('ignore', [])

        def keep_saving_config(self, timeout=1000):
            try:
                self.config = self.read_config()
                # print(self.config)
                self.load_config(self.config)
            except:
                pass
            timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
            timer.timeout.connect(self.save_config)
            timer.start(timeout)

        def load_config(self, mydata):
            if not mydata:
                return False
            data = mydata
            # print(data)
            for name, value in vars(self).items():
                key = name
                type_name = type(getattr(self, name))
                # Below is line 37 which the question line is.
                # parent_name = self.get_parent_name(value)
                # if name in self.config_ignore:
                #     print('name:%s'% name)
                #     continue
                # if type_name in self.config_ignore:
                #     print('type_name:%s'% type_name)
                #     continue
                # if parent_name in self.config_ignore:
                #     print('parent_name:%s'% parent_name)
                #     continue
                def get_value(key, data_dict):
                    '''get value in dict'''
                    if isinstance(data_dict, dict):
                        for x in data_dict:
                            if x == key:
                                return data_dict[x]
                            elif isinstance(data_dict[x], dict):
                                tmp = get_value(key, data_dict[x])
                                if tmp:return tmp
                                else: continue
                if type_name == QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox:
                    conf = get_value(key, data)
                    value.setValue(conf)
                if type_name == QtWidgets.QLineEdit:
                    conf = get_value(key, data)
                    value.setText(conf)
                if type_name == QtWidgets.QTextEdit:
                    conf = get_value(key, data)
                    value.setText(conf)
                if type_name == QtWidgets.QCheckBox:
                    conf = get_value(key, data)
                    value.setChecked(conf)
                if type_name == QtWidgets.QTimeEdit:
                    conf = get_value(key, data)
                    mytime = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', conf)
                    value.setTime(QtCore.QTime.fromString(mytime, "hh:mm:ss"))
                if type_name == QtWidgets.QDateEdit:
                    conf = get_value(key, data)
                    value.setDateTime(conf)
                if type_name == QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit:
                    conf = get_value(key, data)
                    value.setDateTime(conf)
                if type_name == QtWidgets.QRadioButton:
                    conf = get_value(key, data)
                    value.setChecked(conf)
                if type_name == QtWidgets.QComboBox:
                    conf = get_value(key, data)
                    value.setCurrentIndex(conf)
                if type_name == QtWidgets.QSpinBox:
                    conf = get_value(key, data)
                    data.setdefault(key, value.setValue(conf))
                if type_name == QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox:
                    conf = get_value(key, data)
                    data.setdefault(key, value.setValue(conf))

        def get_parent_name(self, obj):
            layout_list = [QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout,
                    QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout,QtWidgets.QGridLayout,QtWidgets.QFormLayout]
            parent = obj.parent()
            if type(parent) == QtWidgets.QWidget:
                children = parent.children()
                for child in children:
                    if type(child) in layout_list:
                        return child.objectName()
            return parent.objectName()

        def get_config(self):
            data = {}
            for name, value in vars(self).items():
                key = name
                type_name = type(getattr(self, name))
                if type_name == QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox:
                    data[key] = value.value()
                if type_name == QtWidgets.QLineEdit:
                    data[key] = value.text()
                if type_name == QtWidgets.QTextEdit:
                    data.setdefault(key,value.toPlainText())
                if type_name == QtWidgets.QCheckBox:
                    data[key] = value.isChecked()
                if type_name == QtWidgets.QTimeEdit:
                    time_str = value.time().toString("hh:mm:ss")
                    data[key] = time.strptime(time_str,'%H:%M:%S')
                if type_name == QtWidgets.QDateEdit:
                    date_str = value.date().toString("yyyy/MM/dd")
                    data[key] = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str,'%Y/%m/%d')
                if type_name == QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit:
                    dt_str = value.dateTime().toString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss")
                    data[key] = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_str,'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
                if type_name == QtWidgets.QRadioButton:
                    data[key] = value.isChecked()
                if type_name == QtWidgets.QComboBox:
                    data[key] = value.currentIndex()
                if type_name == QtWidgets.QSpinBox:
                    data[key] = value.value()
                if type_name == QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox:
                    data[key] = value.value()
            def tree_dict(data):
                widgets = list(tuple(data))
                for widget in widgets:
                    tmp_obj = getattr(self, widget)
                    parent_name = self.get_parent_name(tmp_obj)
                    if parent_name in self.config_category:
                        if parent_name in data:
                            data[parent_name][widget] = data.pop(widget)
                        else:
                            data[parent_name] = {widget:data.pop(widget)}
                return data
            return tree_dict(data)

        def save_config(self, data = None, path = None):
            if path == None:
                path = getattr(sys.modules['__main__'], '__file__', 'data.pkl')
                path = os.path.basename(path.replace('.py', '.pkl'))
            if not data:
                self.config = self.get_config()
                data = self.config
            output = open(path, 'wb')
            pickle.dump(data, output)
            output.close()

        def read_config(self, path = None):
            data = {}
            if path == None:
                path = getattr(sys.modules['__main__'], '__file__', 'data.pkl')
                path = os.path.basename(path.replace('.py', '.pkl'))
            try:
                input_file = open(path, 'rb')
                data = pickle.load(input_file)
                input_file.close()
            except:
                pass
            return data

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        from Ui_ui_config import Ui_Dialog
        class Example(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Dialog, UiConfig):
            def __init__(self):
                super(Example, self).__init__()
                self.setupUi(self)
                self.set_config({'category':['myframe','Layout','gridLayout'],
                                 'ignore':['lineEdit', QtWidgets.QTextEdit]})
                self.keep_saving_config(1000)
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        ex = Example()
        ex.show()
        print('self.config:%s' % ex.config)
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```